# Customizer Active Callback not working

Tags: theme-development, theme-customizer

From some reason my `active_callback => 'is_front_page'` is not working and therefore not showing up inside the customizer on the front-page. I have definitely set my front page to static and selected the home page in the reading settings. I don't know what's wrong with it.

I appreciate the help :)

**Code:**

`functions.php`

```
// Customizer
function themeE4K_customize_register( $wp_customize ) {
    // Add Settings
    $wp_customize->add_setting('slider_one', array(
        'default-image' => get_template_directory_uri() . '/assest/imgs/featureProducts/product1.png',
        'transport'     => 'refresh',
    ));
    $wp_customize->add_setting('slider_two', array(
        'default-image' => get_template_directory_uri() . '/assest/imgs/featureProducts/product1.png',
        'transport'     => 'refresh',
    ));

    // Add Section
    $wp_customize->add_section('slider_image', array(
        'title'           => __('Slider Images', 'e4k-theme'),
        'description'     => __('Slider Images for the Home Page of the E4K Theme'), 
        'priority'        => 10,
        'active_callback' => 'is_front_page',
    ));

    // Add Controls
    $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Image_Control( $wp_customize, 'slider_one_control', array(
        'label' => __('Slider Image #1', 'e4k-theme'),
        'section' => 'slider_image',
        'settings' => 'slider_one',
    )));
    $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Image_Control( $wp_customize, 'slider_two_control', array(
        'label' => __('Slider Image #2', 'e4k-theme'),
        'section' => 'slider_image',
        'settings' => 'slider_two',
    )));    

}
add_action('customize_register', 'themeE4K_customize_register');
```

Comment: try refreshing your permalinks

Comment: ??? I don't think the permalinks has anything to do with the Customizer `active_callback` function @GuruTom

Comment: Do you have any Loops to do with this code? If I remember right the active_callback requires one?

Comment: As far as I know it doesn't require a loop for what I need - [WordPress Customizer API](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/customizer-api/) I've copied some of the code from here about half way down the page there is a section on the active callback function by looking at this you will see when you enables the active callback for the front-page the Site Title hides it self if your not on the front-page

Comment: I tried your code and it is working as expected.

Answer (score 2):

I have copy-pasted your function into my dev install and your two controls show up in the customizer, both with a static front page and with a blog posts front page.

So something is messing with `is_front_page` in your install. If I were you I'd echo [the conditions in function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/is_front_page/) to see if something is wrong there. It could be a stupid database writing error.